# python can't use function in submodule

Tags: python, methods, module

My folder structure is like this:

```
pythonstuff/
    program.py
    moduleA/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

Here's my code for `bar.py`:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

Here's my code for `program.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from moduleA import bar
bar.hello()
```

I run `$ python3 program.py`

Somehow I get an error:

```
File "program.py", line 3, in <module>
bar.hello()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

Edit: my `__init__.py` file is empty.

Edit2: After trying everything I finally realized I had a `bar.py` in the root directory which actually contained the `hello()` method. `bar.py` in `moduleA/` directory was empty.

Comment: whats in your __init__ file?

Comment: the init file is empty

Comment: It runs as expcted for me under Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux. Check your PYTHONPATH???

Comment: do you have any old bar.pyc files?

Comment: oops, I had a bar.py in the root directory, which contained the code originally posted in my question. the bar.py in my moduleA directory was a blank file. moving the file from root directory to the moduleA directory fixed the problem. should i delete this question or...?

Comment: @bvpx, up to you, you could always add the answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Add this into it

```
import os

__all__ = []

for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module != '__init__.py' and module[-3:] == '.py':
        __all__.append(module[:-3])
```

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all**
>   variable, described later.

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

So with that code you're explicitly adding the modules in moduleA into the all variable. [This explains the all variable](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)

Comment: `__all__` is used for wildcard imports.